# Ошибка при работе ListView

Tags: java, android

Возникла ошибка при переходе с первого фрагмента списка на новую `Activity`. Есть `java.class` - `sp1` и `java.class` - `spisok`. Хочу осуществить переход с первого элемента списка на активность `spisok.xml`.

Вот существующий код:

```
public class sp1 extends ListActivity
{
    final String[] Spisok = new String[]{"Что", "Как", "Для кого"};
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Spisok);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if (position == 0)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), spisok.class);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Однако, при нажатии на первый элемент списка - "Что" выдает ошибку. С чем может быть связано, хотя все объявлено в Манифесте, или не хватает кода?

Comment: а ошибка какая? напишите stack trace

Comment: А как узнать stack trace ?

Comment: Это ваша ошибка и есть, которая пишется в лог (обычно красным цветом)

Comment: В самом коде красным цветом ошибка не выделяется, но после запуска приложения и нажатия на первый элемент списка появляется надпись о том что в приложении произошла ошибка и все. Возможно все дело в нехватке нужного кода.

Comment: почитайте уроки по Андроид на тему *LogCat, stacktrace, debug*

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), spisok.class);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

замените на

```
Intent intent = new Intent(sp1.this, spisok.class);
startActivity(intent);
```